# NASM says "Invalid combination of opcode and operands"

Tags: assembly, nasm, opcode, operands

I just started learning assembly programming. I am using NASM on linux.
I wrote this code that's basically meant to calculate the somethingth power of something and I know it's probably not exactly good, but I really don't care at this point, all I want is just SOME idea why I keep getting that error, because I have tried to modify and switch operands and operations and everything in the section where the problem is, but if anything that only gave me more error messages.
As I said, I'm really, really new to this whole stuff and I might just be stupid.
The Problem must be in one of these lines. If you need it, of course I'll post more of the code, I just don't want you to have to go though 70-80 lines of weird, unnecessarily complicated code. I just want to know what COULD be a possible reason for this happening, because I'm really, really desperate right now and also I have reached the point where thinking about it and not having any new thoughts just makes everything worse.
I'll just leave this part here. But I'll give you whatever you need to know to help.

```
    mov dword [power], 2
    mov ecx, 0

while:
    mov eax, [neededforloop]
    cmp eax, ecx
    je endwhile

    mov eax, [power]
    mul eax, 2
    mov [power], eax

    mov eax, ecx
    add eax, 1
    mov ecx, eax

    jmp while
```

Comment: Also, I made sure the number will not exceed 32 bits, so, if I didn't do that completely wrong, that should not be part of any problem.

Comment: 1. I see here no definition of `power`. 2. You have two `mov`'s on same line, and `mov`, `cmp` and `je` on another line, are those only in your question or in your code too? 3. You should be able to find out the problematic line by first commenting out all lines but one line of your code, then assemble, then uncomment some lines more, reassemble, if it works, uncomment some more, reassemble... and when the assembler gives you an error, comment out some of the lines you just uncommented, reassemble, etc., until you find the precise line with the problem.

Comment: You don't have to be so concerned (spend so much time) with letting us know you're just starting out in assembly, so long as you share enough information about your problem and how you've tried to solve it, you should get answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Surely nasm has given you the line number ... that should have pointed you at `mul eax, 2`. In turn, you should have then looked that instruction up in the reference manual and noticed that there is no `mul` instruction that accepts an immediate as an operand. There is such a one for `imul` though.

TL;DR: change `mul eax, 2` to `imul eax, 2` (which is really a shorthand for `imul eax, eax, 2`).

PS: You should use shifts to multiply by 2.

- https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mul  only has the one-operand form.
- https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/imul has `imul r, r/m` and `imul r,r/m,imm` forms that you can use for signed or unsigned.   As well as widening one-operand signed multiply.

Comment: Thank you! That was totally me being stupid. Now it does assemble, I just don't really think it does what it's supposed to. But that's okay, I think I just got lost trying to fix it and broke something else. Would you mind explaining how to do that using shifts?

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out. Thanks for the idea! I feel so stupid right now. That was so obvious. Thank you, really. I have a habit of making things waaaay more complicated than they should be.